# Как программно нажать на кнопку которая обрабатывается через OnTouch?

Tags: java, android, touch

Есть 2 кнопки которые обрабатываются с помощью `OnTouch`. Я подключаю геймпад к смартфону, и нажатия на аналог должны выполнять ту же работу что и эти 2 кнопки.
Нажатия аналогов на геймпаде работают подобно `onTouch`

Как мне программно нажимать/удерживать такие кнопки если я получаю информацию из `onKeyDown`?

P.S. Обработчики этих кнопок в `OnCreate`?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вбиваем в гугл

> [android ontouch programmatically](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20ontouch%20programmatically)

2. Идём по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902985/3212712)
3. Копируем код:

   ```
   // Obtain MotionEvent object
   long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
   long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
   float x = 0.0f;
   float y = 0.0f;
   // List of meta states found here:     developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
   int metaState = 0;
   MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
       downTime, 
       eventTime, 
       MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
       x, 
       y, 
       metaState
   );

   // Dispatch touch event to view
   view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
   ```

Comment: но чужое приложение так не нажмёшь, там рут права нужны уже...

Comment: @pavel, про чужое, вроде, и не было в вопросе сказано...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб будет ли это работать в моем варианте ? Как я понял здесь мы заранее задаем как долго будет зажата кнопка, а мне не подходит такой вариант

Comment: @AmirShabanov, надо пробовать. Попробуйте время одинаковое поставить...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб этот вариант у меня совсем не сработал, на view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent); ругается

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в примере который вы показали, там все в одном блоке view.setOnTouchListener, и обработчик, и нажатие программное, у меня с другого метода совсем надо нажимать ее

Comment: @AmirShabanov, я не понимаю в чём у вас проблема и что за ошибка. У вас нету доступа к переменной View? Если да - то сделайте её переменной класса или заново найдите в разметке.